# Click event isn’t firing when the user clicks on the part within the span tags

Tags: jquery, show, html, onclicklistener

The `Click` event to open this element isn’t firing when the user clicks on the part within the `<span>` tags, and adding a separate `click` function for `"#dropdown_box1 span"` didn't correct the problem.

**Update -** I created a fiddle which demonstrates the problem when you try clicking on the text http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/ezxSF/12/

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dropdown_box1").click(function () {
        $("#select1").show();
    });
    var timeoutID;
    $("#select1").mouseleave(function () {
            timeoutID = setTimeout(function () {
                $("#select1").hide();
        }, 800);
    });
        $("#select1").mouseenter(function () {
        clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    });
    $("#dropdown_container1 ul li a").click(function () {
        var text = $(this).find("input").val();
        var text_edited = text.replace(/_/g, " ");
        var currentHtml = $("#dropdown_box1 span").html();
        $("#dropdown_box1 span").html(currentHtml.replace(currentHtml, ''));
        $("#dropdown_box1 span").append(text_edited);
    });
    });
```

HTML

```
<div id="dropdown_box1"><span>Select</span></div>
<div class="dropdown_container" id="dropdown_container1">  
    <ul id="select1"> 
        <!-- Several List Item Elements --> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That event fires for me. Is `dropdown_container1` hidden by any chance?

Comment: @nick_w: Yes it is :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `click` event is calling `$("#select1").show();`, but this won't have any effect if the parent is hidden.

Instead, try `$("#dropdown_container1").show();` You might also need to `$("#select1").show();`, it would depend on whether that element is also hidden.

**Edit:**

Based on your jsFiddle, this worked for me: `$(".dropdown_container ul li ul").show();`

**Edit 2:**

My approach only works if the `div` is clicked, not the `span`. Try this:

Change the dropdown click event to look like this:

```
$("#dropdown_box1").click(function () {
    $("#select1").show();
});
```

Give the `span` an Id: `<span id="select_text">Select Text</span>`

Change the `$('html').click` handler to this:

```
$('html').click(function (e) {
    if (e.target.id != 'dropdown_box1' && e.target.id != 'select_text') {
       $("#select1").hide();
    }
});
```

This will ensure that the menu won't immediately be hidden when the `span` is clicked. Your previous handler was hiding the `select` if the target was not `dropdown_box1`, which would actually negate the `$("#select1").show();` from the dropdown click handler if it was the `span` that had raised the event.

**Edit 3:**

From the comments @JohnS suggested placing the following prior to `$("#select1").show();`:

```
$("#select1>li>ul").hide();
```

This does the job, but there remains the highlighting that is applied when a sub-menu is clicked. This dissappears after a short time, and without the above code the sub-menu would also be temporarily visible (I presume this is the problem you described in the comments).

Interestingly, this worked fine in IE 9 but not in Chrome. It seems the way to avoid it is to simply let the menu handle the mouse clicks for you - the `$('html').click` method is not technically necessary.

The problem with doing this is that there is a delay between clicking a menu item and the thing being hidden. Calling `$("#select1").hide();` during this delay seems to be the cause of the problem.

To get around this, keep the `$("#dropdown_box1").click` as it was in Edit 2, remove the `$('html').click` handler, and change the `$("#select1").mouseleave` to this:

```
$("#select1").mouseleave(function () {
    $("#select1").hide();
});
```

Doing this should avoid the problem with the menus hanging around, though the visual effect of this is that the menus will close more slowly.

Comment: That makes sense but in this particular instance it's actually #select1 which is hidden, not dropdown_container1, because the 'display:none' settings are for .dropdown_container ul

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you so much :-D

Comment: I spoke too soon :-( It works perfectly the 1rst time I click on it, but if I click on it after I've selected a value from one of the nested list items it's opening the nested items too. Any idea how I can rectify that?

Comment: If you don't want the nested lists to show when the list is opened, you should hide them at that time. Try adding `$("#select1>li>ul").hide();` right before you call `$("#select1").show();`

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's different about the code that would require doing that separately?

Comment: @Chaya - I think the code always had this issue. It happens even for your jsfiddle you listed in the comment to Jodes' answer: http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/ezxSF/12/

Comment: @nick_w, @Chaya - I see what you mean about the highlighting. I hadn't worked with a jQuery UI menu before. It's probably not correct to call `.hide()` on the sub-menus. I looked for a menu method to call instead. The "collapseAll" method looks promising, but it only prevents the flash of the submenus if it is called where the menu is hidden, not if it is called just before the menu is shown. That is, use `$("#select1").hide().menu("collapseAll", null, true );`.

Comment: I can't take your last suggestion of removing the $('html').click handler because then the list doesn't close if the user doesn't mouseover that element once they open it (that's why I had to add it). Adding $("#select1>li>ul").hide(); seems to work (I checked in FF, IE, Chrome & Safari), although it does do that annoying thing of jumping down to highlight the selection in some of them.

Comment: @JohnS: Your idea sounds interesting but I'm not quite following you. Would you mind showing me where to use that snippet?

Comment: @Chaya - For the two places where you have `$("#select1").hide();` change them to `$("#select1").hide().menu("collapseAll", null, true);`. That hides the menu, but also collapses it. That way, the next time it is shown, it should be in a collapsed state. I thought it would be preferable to collapse it just before showing it, but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: @JohnS -That did it :-D What an awesome group effort :-D

Comment: @Chaya - I experimented with this again, and although it helps, it's not perfect. It works if you don't re-open the menu real fast, but if you do, you still see the sub-menus flash. As nick_w alluded to, there seems to be a delay with everything associated with these menus.

Comment: @JohnS: Do you think I'm better off using '$("#select1>li>ul").hide();' instead? (there's still that issue of it jumping down to highlight the selection in some browsers with that option)

Comment: No, it's probably best to leave the hiding to the menu control, and just use it's methods, like `collapseAll()`. You could start another question asking why `collapseAll()` has a delay. I'm kind of curious myself.

Answer (score 1):

I created [a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WRVRz/) from what you've given, and it seems to work:

```
<div id="dropdown_box1"><span>Select</span></div>
<div class="dropdown_container" id="dropdown_container1">  
    <ul id="select1"> 
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Can you modify it to replicate the problem?

Edit:

Change the click handler from:

```
$("#dropdown_box1").click(function () {
    $("#select1").show();
});
```

to:

```
$("#dropdown_box1").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#select1").show();
});
```

And now you can also change this:

```
$('html').click(function (e) {
    if (e.target.id == 'dropdown_box1') {
        $("#select1").show();
    } else {
        $("#select1").hide();
    }
});
```

To this:

```
$('html').click(function (e) {
     $("#select1").hide();
});
```

Comment: I just uploaded a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/ezxSF/12/ To see the problem in action, try clicking on the text inside the span tags 'Select Text'

Comment: That's working perfectly the 1rst time I click on it, but if I click on it after I've selected a value from one of the nested list items it's opening the nested items too. Any idea how I can rectify that?

Answer (score 1):

Jodes answer is good. I was curious though if there was a way to do this without having to change the on-click handler for the `'#dropdown_container1'` element.

You could change the on-click handler for the `<html>` element to:

```
$('html').click(function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('#dropdown_box1') || ($('#dropdown_box1').has(e.target).length > 0))     {
        $("#select1").show();
    } else {
        $("#select1").hide();
    }
});
```

And you really don't need to do the `.show()` in here. This could be shortened to:

```
$('html').click(function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('#dropdown_box1') && ($('#dropdown_box1').has(e.target).length == 0))     {
        $("#select1").hide();
    }
});
```

Too bad jQuery doesn't have a method that makes this more readable, like `isDescendantOf()` or `hasDecendant()`.